# scikit-learn: SVR prediction output is constant

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a regression with SVR and I found a problem in the process, the regression with random data is ok, but I tried it with my data, and with all of these three kernels the prediction's output is constant (see the plot). Here is a piece of my data, maybe the problem is here, but I cant'see why.

data.csv

```
2006,46,97,97,0.04124
2006,47,97,97,0.06957
2006,48,115,97,0.06569
2006,49,137,115,0.05357
2006,50,112,137,0.04132
2006,51,121,112,0.06154
2006,52,130,121,0.02586
```

And here is the code I'm using.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Importing data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = data.as_matrix()

#Random data generator
#datar = np.random.random_sample((7,21))
#inputdatar = datar[:,0:4]

inputdata = data[:,0:4]
output1 = data[:,4]

svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf',gamma=1)
svr_rbf.fit(inputdata,output1)
pre = svr_rbf.predict(inputdata)
axis = range(0,data.shape[0])

plt.scatter(axis, output1, color='black', label='Data')
plt.plot(axis, pre, color='red', label='Regression')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I think maybe it's hyperparameter tuning problem, but I'm not sure if the data would cause a problem as well. Any lights?

Comment: Where's the plot? And what is your polynomial implementation?

Comment: I'll add the plot. The polynomial implementation i was refering to change SVR's kernel from rbf to poly.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit, think doesn't change the answer it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your data (in particular, the target variable) isn't scaled.

The SVR implementation in scikit-learn has a parameter, `epsilon`, that controls the loss function. Quoting from the docs, "It specifies the epsilon-tube within which no penalty is associated in the training loss function with points predicted within a distance epsilon from the actual value."

The default value of `epsilon` is 0.1. As you can see, all of your predictions are within 0.1 of the true value, so the loss is zero.

I'd fix this by scaling (normalizing) your data, or by using a different (smaller) value of `epsilon`. For instance, with `epsilon` equal to 0.001, I get a very non-linear curve that fits the data perfectly (probably not what you want either, to be fair).

Comment: Thanks, @vbox! Do you think normalizing is better than smaller epsilon?

Comment: In general, I'd say that normalizing is a better approach. For instance, SVR uses regularization, and it is well-known that regularization only makes sense when the features have been normalized first. See for instance, [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111017/question-about-standardizing-in-ridge-regression).

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of scaling your data. I believe you can solve that simply by using a StandardScaler from sklearn Here is some sample code that I used:

```
# For SVR we need Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
# Scale x and y (two scale objects)
x = sc_x.fit_transform(x)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```